# Sort integers having special character in Java

Tags: java, comparator

I have a problem where I need to sort Integers separated by hyphen either in ascending or descending order.

I tried using

```
Collections.sort(list, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

Where `list` is an instance of `ArrayList` created, but its not giving me the exact result.

The arrayList looks like this:

```
[91,95,96-1,94-2,94-1,100-2].
```

The expected way is:

```
[91,94-1,94-2,95,96-1,100-2]
```

Comment: Is this a `List<String>`? What is the acutal output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the default sorting on Strings will use a lexicographical order, whereas you intend to sort the Strings in a numerical order (and if the first number is equal, by the second number). A way to accomplish this is by using two Comparators:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("96-1","91","94-2","100-2","94-1","95"));
System.out.println("Unsorted: "+list);

Comparator<String> primaryComparator =
  (a,b)->Integer.valueOf(a.split("-")[0])
          .compareTo(Integer.valueOf(b.split("-")[0]));
Comparator<String> secondaryComparator =
  (a,b)->Integer.valueOf(a.split("-")[1])
          .compareTo(Integer.valueOf(b.split("-")[1]));
list.sort(primaryComparator.thenComparing(secondaryComparator));
System.out.println("Sorted: "+list);
list.sort(primaryComparator.thenComparing(secondaryComparator).reversed());
System.out.println("Sorted in reverse: "+list);
```

[**Try it online.**](https://tio.run/##pZDBTsMwDIbveworpxTWaEWANAaTECckEIfBadrBa8PISJMqSYsmxLMXN5uGGBMguMSx/Tv/Fy@xwXRZPLetKivrAiypIOqgtDgY9XKN3sMtKvPaA6jquVY5@ICBQmNVASW1@CQ4ZRbTGaBb@KRTAtwoH87XjTFoSuACjHyBS@dwFZtjHu9eoO9yzoanacb6bBiP4/SIQjYYxEhprJ6wJBnF9ycrH2QpbB1ERSZBG84ejKcfyOIM2GFnSdKovbJlhQ6DdVsiminRrT46hMexP0/S8bUJciGdaFDX8u6Ro/CVVsSXsmQ6mCUij0Py3vJd6XxHumHd4@9lbk3xF4Ls9wTZlqDbhuiWw798XIQnadYpkfE9YN@tfLK78P@7CScb6bws@M/GoAxs5J8Y3npvbfsO)

As for the comparators themselves, I assumed the Strings in the list are always valid, and always of the form `\d+(-\d+)?`, so either an integer, or two integers separated with a hyphen. (If this is not the case, you might want to add some additional checks/validations with a custom Java 7 style comparator to make it more readable then the Java 8 style lambdas.)

The `.split("-")[0]` / `.split("-")[1]` will split this String on the hyphen, and takes either the first or last integer depending on the comparator. It will then convert this to an integer with `Integer.valueOf(...)`, and will use the default integer comparing builtin `Integer1.compareTo(Integer2)`.

Comment: @Chandru Appaji if this answer works for  you, you should accept and upvote.